# minimization with a negative cost function: works in MATLAB, not in Python

Tags: classification, python

I'm trying to use a particular cost function (based on doubling rate of wealth) for a classification problem, and the solution works well in MATLAB. See https://github.com/acmyers/compareCostFXs

When I try to do this in Python 2.7.6 I don't get any errors, but it only returns zeros for the theta values.

Here is the cost function and optimization method I've used in Python:

```
def costFunctionDRW(theta, X, y):

    # Initialize useful values
    m = len(y)
    # Marginal probability of acceptance
    marg_pA = sum(y)/m
    # Marginal probability of rejection
    marg_pR = 1 - marg_pA

    # =============================================================
    pred = sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))
    final_wealth_individual = (pred/marg_pA)*y + ((1-pred)/marg_pR)*(1-y)
    final_wealth = np.prod(final_wealth_individual)
    final_wealth = -final_wealth

    return final_wealth

result = scipy.optimize.fmin(costFunctionDRW, x0=initial_theta, \
                   args=(X_array, y_array), maxiter=1000, disp=False, full_output=True )
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What type of data is `y`?  Is it an int or a float?  Do you use `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: y is an int... changed it to a float and solved the issue! thanks a ton!

Comment: Great!  I have added the answer as an answer below, please mark it as correct so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with division on python 2.x.  In python 2.x, division involving two integers produces an integer result.  So `1/2==0`.  Python 3.x does not have this problem, `1/2==.5`.

There are two ways to avoid this.  First, you can always convert one value you a float.  So `1./2==0.5` and `1/2.==0.5`.  However, you have to remember to do this everywhere, and if you forget it can lead to hard-to-find errors.

The more reliable method is to always put this at the top of your code: `from __future__ import division`.  This will switch python 2.x to the python 3 behavior, so `1/2==.5`.  In python 3.x it does nothing, so it also makes your code python 3.x compatible in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If your number of cases is large, you may be running into a problem of numerical underflow in the line

> final_wealth = np.prod(final_wealth_individual)

If each value of `final_wealth_individual` is between 0 and 1, multiplying them all together can lead to a result that is too small to represent as a floating point number, resulting in a value of 0.

To address this issue, take the log of `final_wealth_individual` and add them together instead of multiplying.  Note that this will cause `final_wealth` to be negative, so you will not need to multiply it by -1 as you are currently.

Comment: No luck with this solution.  I'm also only using 100 examples/cases.

Comment: Can you expect the output values from each iteration of the optimization? Is it ever non-zero?

Comment: yeah, if I understand what you're saying. I'm starting with initial_theta = np.array([0,0,0]) and when calculating line by line I get a result of final_wealth = 0.1335, then I tried initial_theta = np.array([-0.1,0,0]) and got final_wealth = 0.0433.  So that part is working properly (and same as my MATLAB solution).  But I also tried changing the initial_theta to non-zero values and running the optimization function and ended up with that same non-zero initial_theta.  So it seems that the optimization isn't running any iterations...

Comment: Sorry, that should say "inspect" rather than "expect". It seems like you caught the drift though.

Comment: fyi, the optimization is exceeding the max iterations, yet the result is not changing at all from the initial_theta

Comment: TheBlackCat solved it, but thanks for your help Ryan!

Comment: Make sure that the correct answer gets posted as an answer and marked correct, not just left as a comment above.